# re.split to remove url in input text preprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

in the previous dataset i already do text preprocessing insdide a csv file so i do this

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', dtype=str).apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
#open and lower casing all the data 

#DELETE URL (HTTPS/HTTP)
df['DEL_URL'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: re.split('https:\/\/.*|http:\/\/.*', str(x))[0])
#delete all the text in the columns called 'text' that have https://(anything) and delete all the text that have http://(anything)
df['DEL_URL'] = df['DEL_URL'].apply(lambda x: re.split('pic.tw*', str(x))[0]) 
#delete all the text in the columns 'DEL_URL' that have pic.tw(anything) because i have text that have pic.twitter sometimes
```

my dataset in the csv as an input is :

```
1. test this is my test https:///testing.com
2. test this is my test pic.twitter:///testing.com
output :
1. test this is my test
2. test this is my test
```

NOW , I want to do lower casing and delete the url like above on input text without save it as csv, so i have this code to prediction with classiffier and do some feature selection
i run the code, then inputing the text "test this is my test https:///testing.com pic.twitter/xxd123"

```
import re
##class
class prepro():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def text_pre(self,new_doc):
        lower_case = docs_new.lower()
        #print("lowercase: ",lower_case) #work fine it give me (test this is my test https:///testing.com pic.twitter/xxd123)
        del_url = re.split('https:\/\/.*|http:\/\/.*'," ",lower_case)
        print("delete https or http: ",del_url)  
        #output ['test this is my test ', ''] something wrong with that
        del_url2 = re.split('pic.tw*',del_url) #error 
        print ('del url 2: ',del_url2)#error
        #output error
cs = prepro()

new_doc = input('input text: ') 
#input a text example (test this is my test https:///testing.com)
process = cs.text_pre(new_doc)
x_newtfidf = tfidf.transform(process)  
selectionfeature= seleksi.transform(x_newtfidf) 
predicted = classifier.predict(selectionfeature)
print(predicted)
```

first question why del_rul give me  output
['test this is my test ', ''] i expected only like ['test this is my test ']
then why the del_url2 give me error

````
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\xd\OneDrive\Desktop\something\filename.py", line 180, in <module>
    proses = process.text_pre(new_doc)

  File "C:\Users\xd\OneDrive\Desktop\something\filename.py", line 154, in low
    del_url2 = re.split('pic.tw*',[del_url])

  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 213, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object```
````

Comment: `del_url` is a list. If you pass it to `re.split` as the second argument, you get a TypeError.

Comment: Perhaps substitution function [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) would be a better choice for this use case. You could simply remove urls by replacing them with an empty string, e.g. `del_url = re.sub(r'https?://.*', '', lower_case)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: this is a working solution for your issue:
[codeblock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2587J.png)

```
import re

class prepro():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def text_pre(self,new_doc):
        lower_case = new_doc.lower()
        #print("lowercase: ",lower_case) #work fine it give me (test this is my test https:///testing.com pic.twitter/xxd123)
        del_url = re.split('https:\/\/.*|http:\/\/.*',lower_case)
        print("delete https or http: ",del_url)  
        del_url2 = re.split('pic.tw*',del_url[0])
        print ('del url 2: ',del_url2)
        return del_url2[0]

cs = prepro()
new_doc = 'test this is my test https:///testing.com pic.twitter/xxd123'
#new_doc = input('input text: ') 
process = cs.text_pre(new_doc)
x_newtfidf = tfidf.transform(process)  
selectionfeature= seleksi.transform(x_newtfidf) 
predicted = classifier.predict(selectionfeature)
print(predicted)
```

First of all I want to let you know that I assume you intended to use :
*`lower_case = new_doc.lower()`*
instead of *`lower_case = docs_new.lower()`*.

Besides that,the del_url2 was rightfully producing an error because the .split() method inputs a STRING and returns a list of elements split by the pattern given.
So, according to your code, you first split a string to list and then you are trying to split the list, which produces the error correctly.

Instead you should access the element of the list to further split and then after the second split operation you once again have a list. Because of that you should return only the element that is relevant to you which in case is the *`del_url2[0]`*

I hope this helps. Cheers

PS. One last thing i noticed was that you used *`del_url = re.split('https:\/\/.*|http:\/\/.*',"",lower_case)`* which produces an error because the lower_case is passed as the third argument.